# How to retrieve words separated by a space in a file and store these words separately in an array of pointers in C

Tags: c

//Program to read words from the file and store them in an arrayof pointers and later access them

int main()
{

```
    char *w;
    int i,j;
    w=(char*)malloc(sizeof (char));
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    char *word[max];

    if(f == NULL)
    {
            printf("Cannot open file \n");
            return 1;
    }

    i=0;
    while(fscanf(f, "%s", w) != EOF)
    {        
            printf("%s ",w);
            word[i]=w; 
            i++;
    }       

    for(j=0;j<i;j++) 
    {
            printf("%s", word[j]);
    }
```

return 0;

Comment: Are you sure you want to allocate only 1 byte here: `w=(char*)malloc(sizeof (char)); `

Answer (score 0):

First Don't cast the result of malloc.

```
w=malloc(sizeof (char));// here you are allocating the one byte.
```

change that into take bytes you have to store.

```
w=malloc(1024);
```

While using the array of pointers, each and every pointer you have to do the memory allocation for each pointer to pointing the different pointers.

```
while(fscanf(f, "%s", w) != EOF && i < MAX)
{
     printf("%s ",w);
     word[i]=w; 
     w=malloc(1024); // It is for next index will point to another memory.
     i++;
}
```